# How to keep the width of the lightning:input responsive in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning:input field inside lightning:layoutItem. My requirement is to increase the width of the textbox. So,I am using custom CSS where I am setting the width to 55rem. But looks like the textbox is not responsive. In iPad view, the textbox is flowing out of the screen and in desktop it is working fine. Any help?

> **Component**

```
<lightning:layout> 
       <lightning:layoutItem size="12"
        smallDeviceSize="12"
        mediumDeviceSize="12" 
        largeDeviceSize="12" class="slds-form-element_horizontal">


                 <lightning:input label="Test Value"  required="true"/>  
  </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

> **CSS**

```
.THIS .slds-input{
            width: 54rem;                                                                        
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `smallDeviceSize`, `mediumDeviceSize` etc attributes on layoutItem to make sure the layout is responsive and not use custom css because then you will need to handle break points yourselves.

Comment: yes, I have used smallDeviceSize and mediumDeviceSize but the issue is that that width which I am providing is being considered for all the screens. I want the width should shrink and expand based on screen

Comment: You do not need to provide custom width of 55rem. If you do that, then you will need to handle all media break points yourselves.

Comment: Actually I want to increase the size of the textbox to full screen, that's why I increased the width to 55rem. But other than media is there any other way to make the width responsive?

Comment: I think it will help to paste some of the code here. Please edit the question and add relevant code.

Comment: I've modified the question now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105653/discussion-between-manjit5190-and-gurleen).